# Integration vs numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

When I solve the following integral analytically and numerically the answers are different. Why? how can I get similar answers?

```
a = 10^-6;
t = 10000;
NIntegrate [E^(-w/ a) t, {w, 0, ∞},
MaxRecursion -> 300, AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

here the answer is $0$. But when I solve it analytically, as follows, the answer is $0.01$.

```
Integrate[E^(-w/a) t , {w, 0, ∞}]
```

Comment: `With[{a = 1*^-6, t = 10000}, NIntegrate[E^(-w/a) t, {w, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]]` works, tho.

Comment: `NIntegrate[E^(-w/a) t, {w, 0, \[Infinity]}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]` correct answer, no messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course in this case you can trust the symbolic result of `Integrate`, but the point raised by the question becomes especially important when there is *no* analytical solution.

Here is an example suffering from an even more rapid decay that causes the same numerical problems. Finding the right options for `NIntegrate` isn't so obvious:

```
a = 10^6;

integrand = E^(- a w^w );

Integrate[integrand, {w, 0, Infinity}]

(* returns unevaluated because no symbolic solution exists *)

NIntegrate[integrand, {w, 0, Infinity}]

(* ==> 0., with warning message *)

NIntegrate[integrand, {w, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

(* ==> 0. *)
```

None of these results are what we want.

What I would suggest is to **try symbolic integration first**, but then automatically fall back to numerical integration if that fails. As explained in the documentation for [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) (under "Scope > Basic Usage"), this can be done by simply wrapping `Integrate` in `N`. The advantage for our problem is then that `N` allows a second argument for the desired precision:

```
N[Integrate[integrand, {w, 0, Infinity}], 10]

(* ==> 2.233104982*10^-300622 *)
```

Here, I get a numerical result without having to think about the choice of integration method.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the value of the integral occurs before $w\le 0.00002$.

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-w/a] t, {w, 0, 0.00002}, WorkingPrecision -> 16]
```

> 0.009999999979388476

At `MachinePrecision`, the total value of the integral can be found at $w\le 0.1$.

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-w/a] t , {w, 0, 0.1}]
```

> 0.01

It is therefore not just a question of `MaxRecursion`:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-w/a] t , {w, 0, \[Infinity]}, MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 30]
```

Provides the answer as well, but Mathematica needs to know that it is not just integrating a horizontal line at zero, after all: $e^{-0.1/a}\approx3.563*10^{-43430}$.
Hence the error message.

> Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option. >>

Comment: Using numerical integration all the way to infinity is suspect anyway. Why do it at all?

Comment: @rhomboid, because there are in fact numerical methods for dealing with improper integrals; this is an active area of research.